# Is there a way in Google App Script to get a DomainUser's Last Login Time?

Tags: dns, google-apps-script, provisioning

I have provisioned a number of accounts to users for my domain.

I need to send out some reminders to inactive users, as information is being delivered to their accounts online, and if they are not logging in, they could be missing the information.

Is there any way for me to retrieve the last logged in time for a user or group of users within a Google App Script framework?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that information for now, you could raise an enhancement request on the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list), the only thing you can get to know is whether or not a domain user has logged in once and [agreed the terms of usage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/domain-user#getAgreedToTerms%28%29)